# Generate random number while inserting row

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to insert data in a table called accounts, and one of the fields gotta have a random number, starting with 11 and be 9 digits long, for example 112345673 or 119876543. Is this possible through SQL or I have to do this in PHP then insert there?

Comment: Do you need a *unique* random number, or will any random number do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're inserting one row at a time...

```
--INSERT dbo.table(column1, random_column)
SELECT 'column1_value', 
   '11' + RIGHT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), RAND()), '.', ''), 3)
        + RIGHT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), RAND()), '.', ''), 4);
```

If this is part of a multirow SELECT, you will see the same number assigned to each row, so you'd need to randomize based on other data in each row (or using `NEWID()` as Conrad pointed out), e.g.

```
--INSERT dbo.table(column1, random_column)
SELECT name, '11' + RIGHT(1000000 + ABS(CONVERT(BIGINT, 
  CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), NEWID()))), 7) 
FROM sys.all_objects;
```

(I've commented out the `INSERT` so you can test the result independently.)

Comment: You could also randomize [based on newID](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1522) but I'm sure you knew that

Comment: @ConradFrix yep, there was already another answer with `NEWID()` so thought I would offer a slightly different approach.

Comment: I didn't expect this to return 11 digits but it does as long as the a dot is the digital separator, +1

Comment: @Andomar yes, sorry, should have mentioned that it does rely on regional settings to be "normal" (read:the same as mine). :-)

Comment: For MySQL users: apparently MySQL lacks `newid()`, but has a similar `uuid()` function

Answer (score 3):

This would give you an 11 digit random number.  In case the random number is shorter than 9 digits, it is prefixed with zeroes, so the overall length is always 11:

```
select '11' + right('11000000000' + 
    cast(abs(convert(bigint,convert(varbinary(8),newid()))) as varchar(20)), 9)
```

Comment: This actually leads to 11 digit numbers (OP wants 9). :-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is overly simplistic, but `110000000 + (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10000000)` would be a very lightweight way to produce what you want.

So

```
ALTER TABLE mySchema.myTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_myColumn
DEFAULT 110000000 + (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10000000) FOR myColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP.

`$randnum = "11".rand(1000000, 9999999);`

Then just insert that in the query, and voila.

Answer (score 0):

Possible but not great performance.  Try this.

```
insert into table2(randomNumberColumn)
select convert(bigint,'11' + convert(varchar(100),convert(bigint,right(convert(varchar(100),abs(convert(int,convert(varbinary(16),newid())))),7)))) as a
from table1
```

One issue with this is it doesn't guarantee length of 11 digits.  Sometimes it will be 10 due to the smallness of the number.  Haven't really looked into how to fill in the extra 0 when Random Number Generator comes up with a small number.

Comment: how would I implement this, lets say if I want to insert it in the table?

Comment: `Convert(varchar(` without length? Please don't promote this lazy syntax. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: @aaron modified to be a little bit less lazy but still lazy.

Comment: Note also that this solution doesn't always give 9 digits.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
SELECT '11'+REPLACE(STR(RAND(),9,7),'0.','')
```

...or this slight variation...

```
SELECT '11'+RIGHT(STR(RAND(),9,7),7)
```

...whichever proves faster.

Comment: RAND() sometimes won't have enough digits after the decimal place so you can't rely on this solution to always provide 9 digits.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that is not an issue because STR will provide the trailing zeros if RAND is short, as with the following example: `SELECT '11'+RIGHT(STR(0.25,9,7),7)`, which returns `112500000`